# 'module has not attribute' error when accessing a function

Tags: python

I've my main code in addon.py

In the same folder, there is video.py

In addon.py I do

```
import video

video.play(params)
```

In video.py

```
print 'loaded'

def play(params)
   ..... [omitted code]
```

When executing, I got an error, because

```
Error Contents: 'module' object has no attribute 'play'
```

Also: the `print` is NOT executed.

What's wrong ? It seems that the module is not loaded, but if I try to add a syntax error to the file, the compiler warn me about it, so I'm a lot confused

I tried to rename to my_video, and the error is the same

Comment: You could write a print statement in video.py to see if it's imported.

Comment: I Added print `"bla bla"` to video.py but it's not executed.

Comment: There might be a standard module interfering with your import, trying using another name.

Comment: just in case, which python version you're using?

Comment: It's not that the problem. I tried to rename to my_video, and the error is the same

Comment: Probably it's an old 2.1, because I'm in a embedded environment [xbmc on a raspberry]

Comment: Is the module `video.py` in the same package with the `addon.py`?

Comment: why would raspberry use python 2.1?

Comment: 2nd row of question: "In the same folder, there is video.py". Actaully no package, only 2 files in the same dir

Comment: try print dir(video) to see what's inside your module

Comment: add empty `__init__.py` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the directory with `addon.py` and `video.py` modules add an empty `__init__.py` file to define the package.

```
+- your_package/
        |- __init__.py  
        |- addon.py
        |- video.py
```

[Python packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)